# How to add loading text that dissapears once page is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have a page that loads videos via .load(). I want to add loading text that disappears once the page is loaded. Please can someone tell me how to accomplish this, I have no idea how to tell if the page is finished loading, so I don't know when to remove the loader.

JS

```
 // define var video
var video = $('div.video');

// define click function
$('a').on('click', function( e ) {

    // define var link
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    // Add loading text
    $('.wrap').append('<span class="load">Loading text...</span>');

    // load content into video
    video.load( link + ' .content' );   

    // prevent default href action
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Thanks for the help. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it.

```
video.load( link + ' .content' , function() {
    $('.wrap .load').remove();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it removes the text before the content is loaded. Any other ideas I can try? Thanks

Comment: @ClintonGreen Put a `debugger` statement above the `remove()`. Does it definitely remove the text before the content is loaded?

Comment: Thanks I saw it worked once I did that, I guess it was just too quick to judge and the video might be loaded before it appears. Cheers